# Automatic Movement

Tags: c#, unity, character, controllers

I am making my very first GAME in Unity 2d. At the moment my game consists of 2 walls a floor, a ceiling, and a square which represents the character. After watching some tutorials I have created a C# character controller script which at the moment let's my player jump. Now that I can make the square jump, my next goal is to make the character move without having to press any buttons or making it think a button is being pressed.

Question:

How do I make my square move to the right automatically without any input from the user?

Current Code:

```
usingUnityEngine;  
usingSystem.Collections;

public class SquareControllerScript : MonoBehaviour  
{  
    boolgrounded = false;  
    publicTransformgroundCheck;  
    floatgroundRadius = 0.2f;  
    publicLayerMaskwhatIsGround;  
    publicfloatjumpForce = 700f;  

    void FixedUpdate()  
    {  
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);  
    }  

    void Update()  
    {  
        if (grounded && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))   
        {  
            rigidbody2D.AddForce(newVector2(0,jumpForce));  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have noticed, the `Update` function is executed every frame as long as the `MonoBehaviour` is enabled. You can assign a constant velocity to the `Rigidbody` of the square instance in the `Update` function, so it moves at a constant velocity every frame.

```
if (grounded) {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
    } else {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(2, 0);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Savlon's comment,

- Use `FixedUpdate` when dealing with `Rigidbody`.

Comment: Thanks Aldour.                                                      I just tried "myTransform.position = Vector2.right * Time.time;" which did work in getting the character object to move to the right automatically, but now it isn't affected by the gravity, so I can't jump. I will try your method now.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you may want to experiment with modifying other propeties of a `Rigidbody` as well, such as acceleration and mass. Though these properties are not directly related to your question, these are useful physics-related stuff which you may find useful later on.

Comment: I will definitely keep all of that in mind, before I start working on my next game.

Comment: My square is now able to jump and move right, but having trouble getting it to bounce off the walls at the moment I am using this 'if(collider.tag == "Left Wall") {rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(2,0);

  }'

Comment: This quote is taken from http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html… FYI "FixedUpdate should be used instead of Update when dealing with Rigidbody."